# Join multiple, overlapping classes through overriding?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I was wondering about the following case, but I'm appearently missing the adequate terminology to find any answers anywhere.

Let's start with a common case: I have 3 classes in total. 2 of them inherit from the third one and are to be viewed as specializations.

Now those 3 classs are each still partly abstract and each introduce new pure virtual functions, because this "class structure" can be implemented in different ways for different purposes. And each of these 3 classes access the pure virtual functions from within, so they can not be implemented at a later time.

Then there is a 4th class, that inherits from the 2nd one, in order to specialize the purpose of the pure virtual functions of the 2nd class. There is a 5th class as well, which does the same for the 3rd class.

Now there are still pure virtual functions of the 1st class, which need specializiation according to and beffiting the 4th and 5th class. This is where I am having some issues and I could think of 2 ways to solve this, which don't really satisfy me.

- Have a 6th class inherit from the 1st class and specialize it's purpose befitting to the needs of the 4th and 5th classes and have those classes inherit from the 6th class. This will lead to the "dreaded diamond".

[image]

- Have a 6th class that does not inherit from the 1st class, but which implements the specialized purpose befitting the 4th and 5th class nevertheless. Then have the 4th class and 5th class inherit from the 6th and add an implementation of the pure virtual functions of the 1st class. These implementations do nothing else than call the analogous functions of the 6th, while passing the same parameters etc.

[image]

I'm currently tending to the second solution, since I want to avoid the "diamond dread". But I do not like the additional implementation code that comes with it. Isn't there an easier way to combine different (interfaces/)classes?

For example, using the second solution, I was thinking of something like having the same function prototypes in the 6th class as declared in the 1st class and than telling the compiler that the function of the 1st should be overridden by the function of the 6th class. Sadly, `using myfunction;` inside the class declaration of the 4th and 5th class does not work.

Or asked in general: Is there a way to join "interfaces" - which means that a pure virtual function of a class can be defined by an entirely different class, as long as the prototype is the same and for as long as they are both inherited from a child. I want to avoid duplicating code as much as possible, since I don't want "heavy" classes.

If this ilumination is too abstract, I will come up with an example.

**€dit:** Asking for your opinions: What would be the best solution in this case?

Comment: The short answer is "no", you cannot "outsource" an override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a solution that is pretty similar to the first one:

1. Create the 6th class exactly as you described.
2. Now use the **Bridge design pattern** - have an inner member in both 2 & 3 of type 1. Inject an instance of class 6 to this inner member.
3. Create a tunnel implementation for the virtual methods you're missing in classes 4 & 5. The implementation should be a one-liner that just calls the concrete implementation from 6.

Hope this helps. If you need more help I'll try to elaborate some more.

==============

Following your comment, hope this helps:

Well not exactly. Take the first solution and remove the inheritance of 6 from 4 & 5 (4 inherits 2 and 5 inherits 3 and that's it).

Class 6 inherits 1. Let's call class 1 - Base. Add to both classes 4&5 a member of type Base (let's call it impl).

Let's say class 4 is foo and class 2 is Base2. It will look something like (sorry for the bad c++ syntax, it's been a while since I've written actual c++ code):

```
class foo: Base2
{ 
     private Base* impl; 

     public foo(Base* impl) { this.impl = impl; } 

     void virtualMethod() { 
            this.impl->virtualMethod() 
     } 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I am missing what you are trying to say. This looks rather than a combination of the 1st and second solution?

Comment: `foo` should inherit from class 2, shouldn't it?

Comment: That's my favorite way for multiple inheritance. That's the way I avoided the diamond trap a lot of time during my cpp days, and that's the way I do it when I code now in Java (which doesn't support multiple inheritance)

Comment: Alright, this is definitely a good idea. But I would still need to have 2 'instances' of the base class, which I would like to avoid (I actually thought that this was one aspect of the 'dreaded diamond'). And if I have to implement the pure virtual function in the 4th/5th class anyway, I think it's better to use my 2nd solution, since multiple inheritance is possible in c++ (this would safe the doubled instance)?

Comment: You can create one instance of class 6 and pass it to both 4 & 5 (assuming you don't change any inner members). I don't care for the second solution that much. I would prefer the first one (actually I'd prefer my solution better than both of the solutions you suggested. But that's just me :-) )

Comment: I think I will implement your idea in a different way, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

*The initial idea came from Avi, but I don't know whether this is the best solution yet. I will still post it to have a completive thread*

I will have the interface of the 6th class as an aggregate of the 1st class. The actual type of the aggregate will be controlled at the 4th layer (4th/5th class), where a constant dynamic instance of the adequate class will be passed through the constructor calls up to the 1st class. The pointer will be stored here. Though it will be a pointer of a 7th class, which only defines the interface for the 6th class. I also made the 1st class a friend of the 7th class, so that the interface will only be accessible from there.

[image]